# Proving that $\rho_{12} \geq \frac{(\rho_{13}+\rho_{23})^2}{2} - 1$

Tags: probability, statistics

I am currently trying to show that if $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are rv's with expectation 0 and variance 1, then we have the bound:

$$
\rho_{12} \geq \frac{(\rho_{13}+\rho_{23})^2}{2} - 1
$$

where $\rho_{ij}$ is the correlation between $X_i$ and $X_j$.

In my book, a hint was given to consider the variance of $X_1 + X_2 + sX_3$.

Going along with the hint, I found the variance of it to be:

$s^2 + s(2\rho_{13}+ 2\rho_{23}) + 2(\rho_{12}+1)$.

I instantly saw the connection between this and the bound above as to be what would happen if I took the discriminant to be less than $0$. As in, $b^2-4ac$ for the standard quadratic equation. Meaning, the discriminant of the above equation is:

$$
(2\rho_{13}+ 2\rho_{23})^2 - 4*2(\rho_{12}+1)
$$

I don't see exactly where the hint plays into this as it appears that the bound is received if I assumed that the variance of $X_1 + X_2 + sX_3$ has no real roots. Does anyone have any hints as to where it could be leading me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variance has two real roots, then it takes negative values. A variance is always non-negative. It follows that the discriminant of the equation must be $\le0$.